# React Protected Route - React Component Cannot Be Returned Properly

Tags: reactjs

I am working on a React project. I tried to create a protected route component for the React application that I am building, but I am not sure why I can get `response.status` print properly but cannot get the component return properly. Can anybody please help?

```
import React from 'react';
import { Route, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';


function ProtectedRoute({ component: Component, ...rest }) {

    return (
        <Route {...rest} render={(props) => {

            const identity = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('identity'));

            if (identity !== null && identity !== undefined) {
                if (identity.id !== null && identity.email !== null && identity.id !== undefined && identity.email !== undefined) {
                    
                    // Check with backend
                    Api.get('/checkProtection', {
                        withCredentials: true,
                        headers: {
                            'identity': localStorage.getItem('identity')
                        }
                    }).then((response) => {
                        console.log(response.status);
                        return (
                            <Component />
                        );
                    }).catch((error) => {
                        console.log(error);
                        return (
                            <Redirect to={{ pathname:'/login', state: {from: props.location} }} />
                        );
                    });


                } else {
                    return (
                        <Redirect to={{ pathname:'/login', state: {from: props.location} }} />
                    );
                }
            } else {
                return (
                    <Redirect to={{ pathname:'/login', state: {from: props.location} }} />
                );
            }
        }}
        />
    );
}


export default ProtectedRoute;
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to return the component from callback function of `then()`, when what you should be doing is returning it from the `render` prop callback function.

The solution below, although untested, might work.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Route, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';

function HandleResponse({ location }) {
    const [result, setResult] = useState('');

    useEffect(() => {
        const identity = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('identity'));
        if (identity === null || identity === undefined) {
            setResult('redirect')
        }

        if (identity.id === null 
            || identity.email === null 
            || identity.id === undefined 
            || identity.email === undefined
        ) {
            setResult('redirect')
        }

        // Check with backend
        Api.get('/checkProtection', {
            withCredentials: true,
            headers: {
                'identity': localStorage.getItem('identity')
            }
        }).then((response) => {
            console.log(response.status);
            setResult('success');
        }).catch((error) => {
            console.log(error);
            setResult('redirect');
        });
    }, [])

    if (result === 'success') {
        return <Component />
    }

    if (result === 'redirect') {
        return <Redirect to={{ pathname:'/login', state: {from: location} }} />
    }

    return null;
}

function ProtectedRoute({ component: Component, ...rest }) {
    return (
        <Route {...rest} render={(props) => <HandleResponse {...props} />}
        />
    );
}

export default ProtectedRoute;
```